# How to check a given json-path expression is syntactically correct?

Tags: java, jsonpath, jayway

I need to validate whether the below json-paths are syntactically correct or not:

```
$[*].key1.key2[*].key3.key4 // valid
$[*].key1/key2[*].key3"key4 // invalid
```

Is there any API which can check the above json-path expressions and return true/false in Java ?

Answer (score 1):

Try importing Jayway JsonPath https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath or add below maven dependency in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and use `JsonPath.compile(yourJsonPath);` to validate the json-path. If it doesn't throw `InvalidPathException` then path is valid.

Comment: sure, will try this and get back, thanks @Satish

Comment: If you think this is helpful then please vote up!!

Comment: sure will vote up, I guess your soln should work, but I've not yet tried so let me try this up and then if it works will accept the answer

Comment: 19:19:54.644 [main] DEBUG c.j.j.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $['id']
Exception in thread "main" com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: No results for path: $['id']
       at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.EvaluationContextImpl.getValue(EvaluationContextImpl.java:133)
       at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:187)
       at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:102)
       at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:89)
       at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:502)

Comment: Hi @Satish, it threw the above expcetion with your suggested code-piece, however, I tried around the other supported api and found exact api for my question which is JsonPath.compile(yourJsonPath), but since I got a hint from your suggestion so have upvoted, thanks for the hint/answer, keep guiding

Comment: I've given an edit with your answer updated with my findings, if it is accepted by SO then will accept your answer as well, thanks

Comment: @Manoranjan use try catch block as provided in 1st solution

Answer (score -1):

Use a JSON parser like JSON.parse:

```
function IsJsonString(str) 
  {
      try 
      {
        JSON.parse(str);
      }
      catch (e) 
      {
        return false;
      }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: @Manoranjan why don't you do that?

Comment: isJSON is one more way to check whether syntax is correct or not..

"something".isJSON();
// -> false

"\"something\"".isJSON();
// -> true

"{ foo: 42 }".isJSON();
// -> false

"{ \"foo\": 42 }".isJSON();

Comment: If you don't want to use try catch you can use isJSON()

Comment: @f1sh, actually this code is in javascript, and I don't have set up for javascript, however I tried testing this code from online javascript editor, it's not giving expected result

Comment: @SatishHawalppagol, I do not need to test the json-data rather I need to test the syntax of json-path

Comment: Then you can use isJSON ..it will internally check your syntax too

Comment: looks like you did not get the point dude @SatishHawalppagol, I need to validate json-path not the json-string, also I am not javascript expert, pls share some sample in java so that I can verify,

Comment: a javascript answer is not useful in a java question

Comment: @Manoranjan you should setup your javascript ...then post such question!!

Comment: @SatishHawalppagol, pls refer the question, it's seeking answer in "Java" clearly, pls verify

Comment: This will definitely  help you 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: upvoted your comments!, thanks